# How to work with cookies in Safari following their Prevent cross-site tracking option

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, safari, cross-site

I noticed that when `Prevent cross-site tracking` is checked in Safari, I am unable to set the secure cookies.  I described this issue in great detail in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364879/secure-cookies-not-being-set).

Then how do you set the secure cookies in Express with that setting enabled?

[image]

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite):

```
Values

The SameSite attribute accepts three values:

Lax
Cookies are allowed to be sent with top-level navigations and will be sent along with GET request initiated by third party website. This is the default value in modern browsers.

Strict
Cookies will only be sent in a first-party context and not be sent along with requests initiated by third party websites.

None
Cookies will be sent in all contexts, i.e sending cross-origin is allowed.

None used to be the default value, but recent browser versions made Lax the default value to have reasonably robust defense against some classes of cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks.

None requires the Secure attribute in latest browser versions. See below for more information.
```

---

It says in this [article](https://www.theverge.com/2020/3/24/21192830/apple-safari-intelligent-tracking-privacy-full-third-party-cookie-blocking) that Apple is phasing out third party cookies with Safari.  I'm reading online that third party cookies are generated by a different domain than the one user is visiting, for cross-site tracking, retargeting, and ad-serving.

I am working on a project where the frontend is served on Netlify and the backend is from Heroku.  Since the backend has a different domain than the front-end, the cookies generated from the node express backend are considered Third-party cookies?

Does that mean that I should have both frontend and backend on the same server going forward following this security practice?

Answer (score -2):

Netlify allows you to proxy requests to your backend on a different hostname.
https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service

I'm not sure if it will let you set the cookies that way, Netlify might strip all headers, you should try.

If for some reason that does not work for you then you should either serve frontend and backend from the same hostname or set the cookie with JS on the client-side (which I don't recommend), also you can't set HttpOnly cookie from JS side.